# What does next-logical-line do in emacs

Tags: emacs

I am defining new key bindings for movement in emacs. I want to bind M-n to next-line but I also found next-logical-line which seems to do the same thing.

I know next line moves down a line. 
What does next-logical-line do?

Could you give an example where the 2 commands would do different things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Emacs help (`C-h a next-logical-line`):

> next-logical-line is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   ‘simple.el’.
>
> (next-logical-line &optional ARG TRY-VSCROLL)
>
> Move cursor vertically down ARG lines. This is identical to
>   ‘next-line’, except that it always moves by logical lines instead of
>   visual lines, ignoring the value of the variable ‘line-move-visual’.

Logical lines are lines based on separation by the `newline` character. Or to put it another way, logical lines are based on the text not the display.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/f069ea4f84a94bfbbd444073729f81fdd27c9445/lisp/simple.el#L5853 is the source for next-line().

The docstring contains the following text:

> If the variable ‘line-move-visual’ is non-nil, this command moves by
>   display lines.  Otherwise, it moves by buffer lines, without taking
>   variable-width characters or continued lines into account. See M-x
>   next-logical-line for a command that always moves by buffer lines.

https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/f069ea4f84a94bfbbd444073729f81fdd27c9445/lisp/simple.el#L6767 is the source for next-logical-line()

The implementation for next-logical-line is:

```
(defun next-logical-line (&optional arg try-vscroll)
  "Move cursor vertically down ARG lines.
  This is identical to `next-line', except that it always moves
  by logical lines instead of visual lines, ignoring the value of
  the variable `line-move-visual'."
    (interactive "^p\np")
      (let ((line-move-visual nil))
          (with-no-warnings
                (next-line arg try-vscroll))))
```

We can see that `next-logical-line` is implemented using `next-line`, but with `line-move-visual` set to nil.  By default, this variable is set to t:

```
$ emacs -Q --batch --eval '(message "%s" line-move-visual)'
t
```